# Docusign supporting for Migrating from Notes & Attachments to Files in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Documents added from Docusign for Salesforce is uploading into Notes & Attachments and Not Saving to Files.
We are migrating from Salesforce Notes & Attachments to Salesforce Files and though the config and version is updated in Connection Settings but the document is not Uploading to Files.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant settings to set Connect to write back to Files:

First is the Salesforce API version, which must be set to '39'. To check that, log in to DocuSign > Go to Admin > Connect > Salesforce > Reconfigure Login > *Salesforce SOAP Web Services API Version*. You'll need to enter SFDC Admin Credentials in order to save that change.

Once the API version is set to 39, check *Use Content Files* under System Settings.